# The exponential distribution belongs to the exponential family

Tags: self-study, exponential-distribution, exponential-family

I'm new here.
I'm trying to proof that the exponential distribution belongs to the exponential family, but I don't know how to do that. Can you help me?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: There’s evidence on the Wikipedia article for exponential family distributions. This sounds like a homework/practice question though, so please tag as [tag:self-study]. What have you tried so far? What do you already understand, and where are you stuck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:

[From Wikipedia:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_family)

> A single-parameter exponential family is a set of probability distributions whose probability density function (or probability mass function, for the case of a discrete distribution) can be expressed in the form $f_X(x\mid\theta) = h(x)\,\exp\!\bigl[\,\eta(\theta) \cdot T(x) +A(\theta)\,\bigr]$ where $T(x),h(x),η(θ),$ and $A(θ)$ are known functions.

[and](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution)

> The probability density function (pdf) of an exponential distribution is $$ f(x;\lambda) = \begin{cases}
> \lambda  e^{-\lambda x} & x \ge 0, \\
> 0 & x < 0.
> \end{cases}$$

Your mission, should you choose to accept it, is to find suitable $T(x),h(x),η(θ),$ and $A(θ)$ to demonstrate the exponential distribution pdf is of an exponential family form. It is not particularly difficult, especially if you spot $\exp\!\bigl[\,\eta(\theta) \cdot T(x) +A(\theta)\,\bigr] = e^{A(\theta)}e^{\eta(\theta) \cdot T(x)}$.  You can presume $\lambda=\theta$.